MySql Connector/C++ in CMake
I installed MySql connector and i want to use it in my c++ app to connect to database, although i cannot link the library. I tried the way from other stack question so i did:
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.4")
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/mysqlx)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/mysqlx/common)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/mysqlx/devapi)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/mysql)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64)

target_link_libraries(2024__TAB_DSA__8_BRODZIAK
        PRIVATE cpr::cpr
        mysqlcppcon
)

target_compile_features(2024__TAB_DSA__8_BRODZIAK PRIVATE cxx_range_for)

in mine CMakeLists.txt but it produces error
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppcon: No such file or directory

I have path defined to my installed Connector and the includes of header files but i still cannot use the files itself and I am not sure why.

It seems like the linker cannot find the MySQL Connector/C++ library file named mysqlcppcon. This could be due to several reasons:

The library name might be incorrect in the target_link_libraries command.
The path specified in link_directories may not contain the actual library files or is incorrect.
If you are using a different version of the connector or if your system is 32-bit, the library might be under a different folder instead of lib64.

Here's what you can do to resolve the issue:

Verify that the library name is correct. Often, the library file is named mysqlcppconn. If this is the case, update your target_link_libraries command to use the correct name.

Check if the library files (.lib for static linking or .dll and .dll.a for dynamic linking on Windows) are actually present in ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64.

If your system is 32-bit or uses a different directory structure, ensure that you're looking in the right directory for your libraries.

You might need to specify the exact name of the library file without the extension in your target_link_libraries, e.g., if there's a file named libmysqlcppconn.lib, just mention mysqlcppconn.


Here's an example of how you might adjust your CMake configuration:
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.4")
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)

link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64)

target_link_libraries(2024__TAB_DSA__8_BRODZIAK
 PRIVATE cpr::cpr
 mysqlcppconn # Assuming 'mysqlcppconn' is the correct name of your library
)

target_compile_features(2024__TAB_DSA__8_BRODZIAK PRIVATE cxx_range_for)

If none of these steps solve your problem, consider double-checking that you have installed MySQL Connector/C++ correctly and that all necessary environment variables are set up properly. Additionally, make sure that you're using compatible versions of MySQL Connector/C++ with your compiler and build tools.

AI generated content is not allowed on this site.

chatGPT told me exactly that, just a small disclaimer I also tried the [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/latest/usage.html#manual_config] solution but it also produces error. So the CMakeLists is find_package(mysql-concpp REQUIRED PATHS "C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.4") and later target_link_libraries(2024__TAB_DSA__8_BRODZIAK         PRIVATE cpr::cpr         mysql::concpp ) and there is error C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.4/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:225: undefined reference to mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'`
